# Where and when to prepare the user stories in Agile development?

Tags: users, agile-development, project, user-story

I'm using [Mobile-D](http://virtual.vtt.fi/virtual/agile/mobiled.html) which is a substance of Agile methodology. I've been asked to prepare the user stories.

So in case you are familiar with Mobile-D, please tell me in which phase I must add the user stories and if you are not familiar with Mobile-D, just tell me the suitable place for it in Agile SDLC.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Mobile-D, my expertise is more within the Scrum methodology.

I think one thing to be aware of is that, being agile, user stories are not completed in a particular phase. They should be living and iterated upon as the organization learns more about the problem area as the project progresses. And based on that, I think the user stories should be **started** as soon as possible, but kept alive, refined and iterated throughout the project.

If you have a certain phase where you complete the user stories, and after that they cannot be improved, you're not being that agile tbh